# Pull-ups in a mixed voltage environment

Tags: circuit-design, pullup, mixed-signal, review

I'm working on a circuit where a 12 VDC line is switched from a USB-powered microcontroller (`U1`, running at 3.3 V, specs below).  I want to ensure that the switch defaults to ON if the microcontroller is powered off (i.e. unplugged from USB).  The switch I'm using (`U2`, specs below) can be controlled directly from a GPIO pin.  I've come up with two possible methods of doing this; are there any issues with either approach?

**Option 1: Simple pull-up**
Use a 300k Ω pull-up (`R1`) to 12 V on the Enable line; this will ensure that the signal is ON if the microcontroller's pin is high-Z.  An additional 100k Ω resistor (`R2`) connects to ground; this ensures that the enable line is at 3 V when the microcontroller pin is high-Z (this protects the microcontroller from over-voltage).  The resistor values are high enough that I think there should be no issues with the microcontroller driving the line high or low.  There's no ESD diode to V<sub>DD</sub> on the microcontroller (only to ground) so I'm not concerned about back-powering it.  This is my preferred solution.

**Option 2: Switched pull-down**
The switch's enable pin is pulled high via a 100k Ω resistor (`R3`) connected to the 12 V rail.  An N-channel MOSFET (`M1`) connected between the enable line and ground can be switched on by the microcontroller to turn the power switch off.  An additional 100k Ω resistor (`R4`) to ground on the MOSFET's gate ensures that it's off when the microcontroller isn't powered.  For board-space reasons I'd rather not take this approach.

Do either of these approaches seem reasonable or is there a better way to do this?  Is there anything I've missed?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvRLBw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**U1: TPS22810 Power switch** ([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps22810.pdf))
Switch is turned on or off via the **EN** pin:
**V<sub>EN</sub>** 0 V .. 18 V, threshold = ~1.0 V (low=off, high=on)

**U2: Teensy 3.1** (MK20DX256VLH7 microcontroller, [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/302/K20P64M72SF1-1126422.pdf), [schematic](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/schematic.html))
GPIO pin specs:
**V<sub>DIO</sub>** -0.3 V .. 5.5 V (input voltage range)
**I<sub>D</sub>** -25 mA .. 25 mA (maximum sink/source current)
**V<sub>OL</sub>** maximum 0.5 V (Low output voltage)
**V<sub>OH</sub>** minimum 2.8 V (High output voltage)
GPIO pins default to input (high-Z)
From the datasheet (p. 11):

> All 5 V tolerant digital I/O pins are internally clamped to V<sub>SS</sub> through a ESD protection diode. There is no diode connection
>   to V<sub>DD</sub>.

**M1: 2B7002 N-channel MOSFET** ([datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/2N7002NXBK-1651338.pdf))
**V<sub>GSth</sub>** 1.1 V .. 2.1 V (gate-source threshold
voltage)

Comment: " Is there anything I've missed?"  Yes everything necessary for  good design/verification specs on inputs and outputs for a simple inverting logic controlled power switch. Like the datasheet, your design specs must be detailed. Not your choices with no specs

Comment: With option 1 you're likely to have current 'leaking' in thru the micro's GPIO pin which might be enough to intermittently power the micro. Go with option 2.

Comment: @brhans  The MK20 only has protection diodes going to ground so I don't think that would be an issue.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 What specific parameters are you referring to?  Also, what do you mean by inverting logic?  The switch specs are >1V=On, <1V=Off.

Comment: I am referring to all the requirements .  One of which are listed in question.  make a list like the datasheets of examples you chose for your requirements.  I won’t ask again.